# Is there a way to use sledgehammer in Isar proofs?

Tags: isabelle, isar

I tried to use the `sledgehammer` command in Isabelle/HOL (2021) **after** the `proof` command, and got an error:

> Illegal application of proof command in "state" mode

If I use it before the Isar `proof` command, then `sledgehammer` works. My question is:

*Suppose a `proof` generates several sub-goals, having proved the first sub-goal somehow, is there a way to use `sledgehammer` in the middle of the `proof` process to try to prove the other sub-goals?*

The more general question is:

*Is `sledgehammer` designed for the old tactics and not suitable for use inside Isar proofs.*

(I first asked this in SO; but did not get a definitive answer. Therefore, I am posting the question here, and deleting it there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work in an Isar proof, however you will want to pull a subgoal into focus. Unless your most recent tactic is something like `induction`, you will find `goal_cases` handy. As an example

```
lemma A B C
proof goal_cases
```

will output a clickable (like with `induction`):

```
  case 1
  then show ?case sorry  (* goal: A *)
next
  case 2
  then show ?case sorry  (* goal: B *)
next
  case 3
  then show ?case sorry (* goal: C *)
qed
```

<sub>(obviously, the comments are not part of the output)</sub>

Then you can use `sledgehammer` after a `show ?case` statement.

> Is sledgehammer designed for the old tactics and not suitable for use inside Isar proofs.

I would not say that apply-scripts are old/outdated, but indeed `sledgehammer` only works where you could also write an apply-style tactic (ignoring the fact that `proof` can take a tactic to open the Isar proof).

---

Of course, you could also write something like this:

```
   ... (* proved subgoal somehow *)
next
   show B
     sledgehammer
```

Comment: It might be convenient to highlight that a proof in Isabelle/Isar cycles through different _modes_ (Isar Reference p. 131). This was very misleading to me at first. Commands like `lemma` put a goal in a **prove** mode, which is preserved after an `apply` command. On the other hand, the `proof` command leaves you in a **state** mode, in which there are no active goals, so to speak--you have to _state_ them using `have` or `show`; this will put you in **prove** mode again (that's why the answer works). Finally, commands like `from` and `then` set the mode to **chain** (1/2)

Comment: (cont'd) which is similar to **state**, but with the addition of previous facts to the active goal. A detailed example is in the [Isar Reference Manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021-1/doc/isar-ref.pdf), p. 37. (2/2)